# How set up speaking links for solr in TYPO3 9

Tags: solr, routes, typo3

Is it possible to setup speaking urls in TYPO3 9 for EXT:tx_solr as it was with RealUrl in prev versions?
I've looked at the example of EXT: news and tried to implement the EXT: solr search, but I do not succeed. I tried that:

```
routeEnhancers:             
      SearchPlugin:
        type: Extbase
        limitToPages:
          # Suche list view - needed for pagination:
          - 36
        extension: Solr
        plugin: Pi_Search
        routes:
          - { routePath: '/page/{page}', _controller: 'Search::search', _arguments: {'page': '@widget_0/currentPage'} }
          - { routePath: '/list/{page}', _controller: 'News::list', _arguments: {'page': '@widget_0/currentPage'} }
          - { routePath: '/tag/{tag_name}', _controller: 'News::list', _arguments: {'tag_name': 'overwriteDemand/tags'}}
          - { routePath: '/blog/{news_title}', _controller: 'News::detail', _arguments: {'news_title': 'news'} }
          - { routePath: '/archive/{year}/{month}', _controller: 'News::archive' }

        defaultController: 'Search::search'
        defaults:
          page: '0'
        requirements:
          page: '\d+'
        aspects:
          page:
            type: StaticRangeMapper
            start: '1'
            end: '100'
```

Comment: It is certainly possible but it would be better if you describe what parameters exactly you want to convert to speaking.

Comment: In the search result, I would like to rewrite the following links: /index.php?id=81&L=2&tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&tx_news_pi1%5Baction%5D=detail&tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=1&sword_list%5B0%5D=bfs&no_cach And /index.php?id=12&L=2&sword_list%5B0%5D=bfs&no_cache=1 For the EXT: news I have already, as well as on the standard page.

Comment: Not directly solr-related then. You are looking for a general information about encoding parameters to speaking segments, which is not solr-specific but a TYPO3 wide thing.

For news, the news extension documentation contains information about creating speaking urls for news. I suggest you start from looking there. Then you should able to do the rest.

Comment: I've looked at the example of EXT: news and tried to implement the EXT: solr search, but I do not succeed.
I tried that:....SearchPlugin: type: Extbase limitToPages: # Suche result view - 36 extension: Solr plugin: Pi_Search routes: - { routePath: '/page/{page}', _controller: 'Search::search', _arguments: {'page': '@widget_0/currentPage'} } defaultController: 'Search::search' defaults: page: '0' requirements: page: '\d+' aspects: page: type: StaticRangeMapper start: '1' end: '100'

Answer (score 0):

EXT:realurl isn't compatible to TYPO3 9.5. Instead with TYPO3 9.5 a new feature called "routing" was established in TYPO3.

You need to add a site configuration to your installation. This can be done via the backend module "Sites".

Afterwards, speaking URLs will work right out of the box for regular pages. If you have any extension installed, you need to add `routeEnhancers` to your site config.

Documentation:

- [Site Handling](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/Index.html#sitehandling)
- [Page based Routing](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/PageBasedRouting.html)
- [Example for routeEnhancers with EXT:news](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/master/en-us/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Routing/Index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply.
I know that the EXT: realurl is no longer compatible with version 9.5. The example for EXT: news I know. In the ETX: news, I have also implemented it, only with the ETX: solrr I can not continue.
Is there an example for the ETX: solr-search?
Thank you very much.

Comment: So you mean the tx_solr GET parameters like `tx_solr[q]`? Did you check the [documentation for route enhancers](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/AdvancedRoutingConfiguration.html)?

Comment: Yes, I did check the documentation for route enhancers. In the search result, I would like to rewrite the following links:

/index.php?id=81&L=2&tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&tx_news_pi1%5Baction%5D=detail&tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=1&sword_list%5B0%5D=bfs&no_cach
And

/index.php?id=12&L=2&sword_list%5B0%5D=bfs&no_cache=1

For the EXT: news I have already, as well as on the standard page.

This is what my "config.yaml" from:

Comment: routeEnhancers:
 
  News:
    type: Extbase
........
.........
SearchPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      # Suche result view 
      - 36
    extension: Solr
    plugin: Pi_Search
    routes:
      - { routePath: '/page/{page}', _controller: 'Search::search', _arguments: {'page': '@widget_0/currentPage'} }
    defaultController: 'Search::search'
    defaults:
      page: '0'
    requirements:
      page: '\d+'
    aspects:
      page:
        type: StaticRangeMapper
        start: '1'
        end: '100'

Comment: @ Peter Kraume, I do not manage to translate the links in the search results, in speaking URL.
The plugin EXT: Solr is registered in several ways: pi_search, pi_frequentlySearched, pi_results.
Maybe you know an example? The examples of EXT: news just confuse me there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's weird because links within the search results are done like every other link within TYPO3 as well. I'd suggest to join the [TYPO3 Slack channel #ext-solr](https://typo3.slack.com/messages/C02FF05Q4). Maybe you can get more specific help there.

Comment: @ Peter Kraume, Thanks for the answer. How can you join this channel? Can you help me there, because I have no account there.

Comment: You can register an account here: https://my.typo3.org/about-mytypo3org/slack